# Display message on logout (flash?)

Tags: form, action, flash

I have looked through previous questions and answers, but don't see the following clearly explained.

When my users visit */logout*, they are successfully logged out and redirected to the website's homepage.

What is not clear to me is how I can detect that action, and display some HTML saying they have been successfully logged out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `postLogoutRedirect` in your `config/general.php` ([docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#postlogoutredirect)) to redirect your users to a specific page, something like `'postLogoutRedirect' => 'your-page'`

If you want to use an existing page, say your homepage, and display an alert you could set `'postLogoutRedirect' => '/?loggedout'` and check for it in your template using:

```twig
{% if craft.app.request.getParam('loggedout') is not null %}
    <p>You have been logged out</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass a unique message through to the target page? I wasn't clear on flash messages either. {% set flashMsg = 'You have just successfully done a thing.' %}